# Nginx proxy_pass to dynamic host

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

At the moment I have a PHP script set up with a chunk of code that reads a file from a dynamic location (which comes from a database) and echo's it out to the user in chunks. It's basically a file streaming script to hide the location of the original file.

However, this comes with a large overhead as PHP is clogging up my server's processes for each download. Instead I'd like to use nginx, and I'm wondering if it's possible to dynamically set the `proxy_pass` directive to a value in my database.

For example, if my website has a page at `http://example.com/download?hash=abcd`, I need to look up the download URL for the hash `abcd` from my MySQL database and then serve that file using nginx and `proxy_pass`.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: What is so costly in your script that it is blocking the server? CPU does not suffer from downloading a file. For the looks of it you might have a problem with child-process limit, not with the script overhead. Try to spawn more php-cgi/fcgi/fpm processes, and nginx workers and it should be ok. Nginx alone won't be able to connet to a database.

Comment: The PHP process used to download a file uses around 5% CPU, but with a lot of simultaneous downloads that adds up. It's not causing a problem as such, as I haven't experienced slowdowns yet however having nginx doing the grunt work would be a lot more efficient than using PHP. I'm aware nginx can't connect to a database, I was thinking something along the lines of having PHP return a header with the real URL which nginx would use to download the file, like what you can achieve with `X-Accel-Redirect`.

Comment: Then you might want to use a lua script `ngx.location.capture` for that, which calls the php-fcgi and processes the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not connect to mysql direct from nginx, but you can add location for proxying like

```
location ~ /proxy/(?<domain>[^/]*)(?<url>/.*) {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://$domain$url;
}
```

and use X-Accel-redirect header in your application which will connect to database, get download url by hash and set for example "X-Accel-Redirect: http://your.domain.com/proxy/other.domain.com/path/to/file.txt".

Comment: Unfortunately this won't hide the original download URL from the user, will it?

Comment: Yes, it will. It will be handled by internal redirect.